# Connect to google meet by selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to connect to google meet using selenium web driver .But when I run my script I see this:
[image]

Translation - "You are not allowed to participate in this meeting"

I can't access google meet because I use selenium web driver. Any ideas how can I pass it?
Actually I need solution like this(see below) when i can access google meeting without google acc (in guest mode by entering some name):
[image]

As I see perfect solution, I run google chrome with guest mode and then I enter some name and join to google meet

I hope to get solution in Java or find out that my problem is not solved in any way or maybe there are some alternatives

Comment: It might be helful to people if you could translate the contents of the image showing the problem into english. (Maybe just add that as text below).

Comment: You're getting detected. Solutions for Python would be, to use [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver